# Converting error when try to UNION ALL temporary tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I created a few temporary tables which I need to union using UNION ALL. This is how it looks in my code:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
INTO #Tab1
FROM dbo.Cust

SELECT X, Y, Z
INTO #Tab2
FROM dbo.Cars

SELECT X, Y, Z
INTO #Tab3
FROM dbo.Colors

SELECT * FROM #Tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Tab2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Tab3
```

Unfortunately, I got an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value .. to data type
> int

However, when I try to union these tables but not as temporary ones, then no error arises. So, the solution below works fine and output is returned properly:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM dbo.Cust

UNION ALL

SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM dbo.Cars

UNION ALL

SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM dbo.Colors
```

Columns X, Y, Z are of the same type as in temp table. I guess there must be an issue with temp tables but don't know what exactly. Where is the problem and why it happens?

Comment: What are the **structures** on those temporary and permanent tables? Most likely, you have a discrepancy in terms of the **datatype** of columns that you combine using `UNION ALL` ..

Comment: Structure is the same, I just select columns from permanent table and create temp table, then select the same columns from temp table to make union afterwards. They have the same structure though. The issue is that `UNION ALL` throws an error when using temp queries and doesn't throw an error when using simple `SELECT .. FROM` queries. And I don't know why

Comment: Do the data type for columns in the temp tables match with the data type of columns of source table?

Comment: How could datatypes didn't match in my scenario? I select columns from source table (e.g. `dbo.Cust`) and insert into `#Tab1`, as you can see in my code. Then I just select the same columns from `#Tab1`, with no datatype change,  and try to make union. That's why it makes me wonder what's wrong